# Collections sort with custom comparator does not work

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, comparator

I have created a custom Comparator to sort an ArrayList of Strings.  I have run it through the debugger and watched it comparing and returning values correctly.  However, my array is not sorted.  Since I am new to Java & Android, there might be something else going on.

After looking at it for a few hours, I can't figure out what .. and since I have been using this site to answer so many other questions, I knew where to come to !

```
    Collections.sort(allWords, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            scoreWord sc1 = new scoreWord((String)o1);
            scoreWord sc2 = new scoreWord((String)o2);
            int i1 = sc1.getScore();
            int i2 = sc2.getScore(); 
            if ( i1 > i2 )
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        public boolean equals(String o1, String o2) {
            scoreWord sc1 = new scoreWord((String)o1);
            scoreWord sc2 = new scoreWord((String)o2);
            int i1 = sc1.getScore();
            int i2 = sc2.getScore(); 
            if ( i1 == i2 )
                return true;
            return false;
        }
     });
```

Comment: For what reason do you need the `equals(String o1, String o2)` method?

Comment: try `compare(Object o1, Object o2)` and `equals(Object o1, Object o2)`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your `compare` method isn't symmetric - it *always* either returns 1 or 0.

Instead, just delegate to `Integer.compare` (if it's available in the version of Java you're using), passing in the scores:

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    scoreWord sc1 = new scoreWord((String)o1);
    scoreWord sc2 = new scoreWord((String)o2);
    return Integer.compare(i1, i2);
}
```

Otherwise do it by hand, which is frankly a pain - if you need this in more than one place, I suggest you write your own implementation of `Integer.compare` to avoid the repetition:

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    scoreWord sc1 = new scoreWord((String)o1);
    scoreWord sc2 = new scoreWord((String)o2);
    return i1 > i2 ? 1
         : i1 < i2 ? -1
         : 0;
}
```

This way you'll have appropriate symmetry:

- `a.compareTo(b) < 0`  implies `b.compareTo(a) > 0`
- `a.compareTo(b) > 0`  implies `b.compareTo(a) < 0`
- `a.compareTo(b) == 0` implies `b.compareTo(a) == 0`

Comment: can you explain or provide a link to this symmetric property?

Comment: It's in the documentation for [`Comparator.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) (It's expressed in terms of sign, but that's the same thing.)

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        scoreWord sc1 = new scoreWord((String)o1);
        scoreWord sc2 = new scoreWord((String)o2);
        int i1 = sc1.getScore();
        int i2 = sc2.getScore(); 
        if ( i1 > i2 ) {
            return 1;
        } else if ( i1 < i2 ) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is what university coding gets you... an assumption that sort algorithms require T/F in the compare :(

Comment: @user882173: pls give me a hint, what you mean by "T/F"?

Comment: @user882173 true or false

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator should return something akin to:

**Return:**
a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

[Source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)